# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token * chrome extension tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

In this repo:https://github.com/ryancbarry/tensorflow-image-recognition-chrome-extension/blob/master/src/background.js This guy makes a chrome extension with tensorflowjs. He uses import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';, but when I try to do that in my background.js, I get an error. He also did not use any tf.min.js file.How is this possible?

Comment: what error do you see and when? During build or runtime?

Comment: That code you're looking at is before compiling/bundling so it's not what is installed. The actual extension is inside the `dist` directory after you run `npm run build` and it doesn't use ES-modules. You can still use ES-modules directly if you declare a [background **"page"**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_migration) (it's not documented anymore but it's still supported) html where your js files should be loaded with `type="module"` attribute. For more info about ES-modules read the documentation or a tutorial.

Comment: @wOxxOm I added <script src="tfjs.js" type = "module">//const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('model.json');</script> in my background.html but I still get the same errors. I've been trying to figure out how to import tensorflow succesfully since the past few days, but I havent been successful.

Comment: Well, to use ES-modules directly, your imported file must also support it by using the ES-modules syntax as explained and shown in the documentation. Evidently tf.min.js doesn't use this syntax so you can't import it using ES-modules syntax **directly**. You can do it if you use a bundler like that other extension does.